# How do I keep a button on screen which is below a listview when there are too many items in the list?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Quick background: I have a portion of my activity in a relative layout. I did this on purpose because I wanted a button directly below a listview. I want the button to move down as the listview expands which is why I set it up this way. I've set the height of the listview to wrap content, this way in the relative layout, the button will move down as the list expands.

Issue: Once the list gets big enough such that the content fills up the screen, the button remains below the list (which is fine) but I can't scroll down the list to reveal the button. The button "disappears" below the list. How can I make it so that I can scroll on the list/screen to reveal my button?

Edit: I do want the button to go off screen, I just want to be able to scroll down to see it again.

Sample code below + images:
3 pics, one showing the intial layout, next you can see the button moves as my list expands, 3rd, eventually the button reaches the bottom and I can't scroll more to click it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workoutList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logExerciseButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/workoutList"
        android:text="@string/log_set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Initial setup]

[image: Moving button]

[image: Button gone can't scroll]

Comment: You could do this with either LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout.. RelativeLayout has performance issues

Comment: Oh the relative layout is a child of a linear layout in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the button as a footer to the listview resulted in the desired behavior: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-footer-in-android-listview

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workoutList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logExerciseButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logExerciseButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/log_set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I still want the button below the list view though, thank you anways!

Answer (score 0):

wrap your ListView with ScrollView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workoutList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        
    </ScrollView>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logExerciseButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        android:text="@string/log_set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try this, I thought the list view was scrollable by default. Also, will this keep the button being able to move down as the list increases? I guess to clarify, I do want the button to go off screen, but I want to be able to scroll down to see it again.

Comment: Hmm yeah that didn't work, it only displays one item now - I think the scroll view is stuck at the top and I can only scroll in that one little part